# Can we replace new server certificate from old server certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

My server certificate will expire at end of the next month. So I am planning to replace it with the new one before it expires. but I need to do some testing with the new certificate (My mobile applications) and if the testing fails Can I replace the old certificate again until I found a way to fix my issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with Windows / IIS and info is based on that background:

1. you can install multiple certs on a server
2. you can assign your new cert to the site while keeping old on the server
3. if new cert fails, reassign old cert to your site

This concept should work with other servers too, but I cannot confirm that for sure

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer